# Adaptable UI in QML

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I am developing a QML application where I have three main views. My code looks like below.

```
SplitView{
    ListView{
        id: firstView
    }
    ListView{
        id: secondView
    }
    WebView{
        id: thirdView
    }
}
```

Now this is working fine, but I would like to do this: when my main window is resized below a certain width (500) I would like to show only one view, so that clicking on the delegate will show the next view (with the possibility of going back to the previous view). So for example clicking on the first view will show the second view and clicking on the second view will show the third view. The approach I want is very similar to the Mail application in Windows 10.
Does anyone know how can this be achieved in QML?

Comment: I don't see a "problem" here, you can perfectly well implement that flow of logic into your QML UI. It can be achieved by "implementing it"... there is no magic that will do all the work for you, if that's what you are wondering.

Comment: Qml SplitView does not give the possibility to show only one view when required and switch between them. It is true that I can use the `visible` property and hide the views I want, but then the UI can't be animated. This is my concern.

Comment: Don't feel obligated to stick to stock UI elements, you have dynamic object creation, animation, states and all the tools you need to achieve your goal.

Comment: So you think I should abandon the use of Qml SplitView?

Comment: If it doesn't work the way you want it to... you don't have a choice. Qt newbs often believe it has a class for everything, but as big as it is, it doesn't have everything, and some of the classes just don't work the way you need them to, so reinventing wheels with Qt is not that uncommon.

Comment: You may want to try the StackView element. As for the adaptive part, you can either use logic to dynamically rearrange the UI, or simply have one big and one small version of the UI driven by the same data and change between them.

Comment: @ddriver thank for the advice. I wonder though, from a purely performance point of view, which approach would be the best? Dynamically rearranging the UI or using the second approach?

Comment: I'd say it will be about the same, the difference is with dynamic arrangement you can use some neat animation, with the second approach it will be at most a "slide" in and out. IMO if you are asking those questions you are getting ahead of yourself. Spend more time learning QML and you will know how to implement exactly what you want. There are at least several different ways to do it, and it is about 30 minutes worth of work once you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've cooked up a crude example, I didn't modularize it deliberately, so you can see how it works in a single source. Also, I don't know how the windows 10 mail application does it, since I don't have it, but it still close enough to your description.

You begin with 3 list views in a row, which are sized to fill the entire UI, but if you reduce the UI size to the minimum of 500, the views will increase in size to fill almost the entire ui, and when you click on a view item, it will move you to the next view, and if you click the showing previous view, you will be returned back to it.

[image]

```
ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 800
    height: 300
    minimumWidth: 500
    visible: true

    Item {
        id: adapt
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        property int sizeUnit: width > 500 ? width / 5 : 400
        property bool isPaged: width == 500 ? true : false
        onIsPagedChanged: { if (!isPaged) { x = 0; page = 0; } }
        property int page: 0

        Behavior on x { NumberAnimation { duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.OutBack } }

        ListModel {
            id: mod
            ListElement { name: "one" }
            ListElement { name: "two" }
            ListElement { name: "three" }
            ListElement { name: "four" }
            ListElement { name: "five" }
        }

        ListView {
            id: v1
            width: adapt.sizeUnit
            height: parent.height
            model: mod
            delegate: Rectangle {
                height: 70
                width: v1.width
                color: "red"
                border.color: "black"
                Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: name }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        if (adapt.isPaged) {
                            if (adapt.page == 0) {
                                adapt.x = -(v2.x - 100)
                                adapt.page = 1
                            } else {
                                adapt.x = 0
                                adapt.page = 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: v2
            width: adapt.sizeUnit
            height: parent.height
            x: adapt.sizeUnit + 10
            model: mod
            delegate: Rectangle {
                height: 70
                width: v2.width
                color: "cyan"
                border.color: "black"
                Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: name }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        if (adapt.isPaged) {
                            if (adapt.page == 1) {
                                adapt.x = -(v3.x - 100)
                                adapt.page = 2
                            } else {
                                adapt.x = -(v2.x - 100)
                                adapt.page = 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: v3
            width: adapt.isPaged ? adapt.sizeUnit : 3 * adapt.sizeUnit - 20
            height: parent.height
            x: v2.x + v2.width + 10
            model: mod
            delegate: Rectangle {
                height: 70
                width: v3.width
                color: "yellow"
                border.color: "black"
                Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: name }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should be enough to get you going. Obviously, for production you can go for more elegant layouting and nagivation, such as use a function for the actual "page sliding" and anchors, the above is just for the purpose of example.

Comment: Yes, this is very close what I want. I guess I will probably have to sacrifice the use of Qml SplitView. The other alternative (very simple) that I experimented with and works pretty well is simply using a QML Loader element. Like below 
`Window{
    id: window
    Loader{
        source: window.width > 500 ? Qt.resolvedUrl("SplitView.qml") : Qt.resolvedUrl("SingleView.qml")
    }
}`

Comment: @daljit97 - I myself have never used the split view, it is there for comparability with the old Qt widgets, IMO it doesn't really have a place in a QML style / "modern" GUI.

Comment: the main reason I use it is because it gives the user to resize the   different views

Comment: You can easily do this without it.

Comment: I just checked the approach using a QML Loader and it seems like it is not good from a perfomance point of view (memory usage of app increases significantly each time the source of the loader is changed)

Comment: @ddriver : could you give an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea of how to solve the problem.

```
    // When width of MainWindow is smaller than 500 stop using SplitView
property bool useSplitView: (width < 500 ? false : true)
onUseSplitViewChanged: {
    if (useSplitView) {
        firstView.anchors.fill = undefined
        secondView.anchors.fill = undefined
        thirdView.anchors.fill = undefined
        firstView.parent = splitView // splitView is id of SplitView
        secondView.parent = splitView
        thirdView.parent = splitView
    }
    else {
        firstView.parent = mainWindow.contentItem // mainWindow is id of MainWindow
        secondView.parent = mainWindow.contentItem
        thirdView.parent = mainWindow.contentItem
        secondView.visible = false
        thirdView.visible = false
        firstView.anchors.fill = firstView.parent
        secondView.anchors.fill = secondView.parent
        thirdView.anchors.fill = thirdView.parent
    }
}
```

When `useSplitView` flag changes you need to enable some kind of touch area on views and switch between them on click.

Comment: Ok I have tried your approach, but I am seeing this `SplitView.qml:571: TypeError: Type error` multiple times  and the SplitView has many bugs when resizing

Comment: @daljit97 Maybe simplier way would be to just maximize one of the views to maximal size and than clear the handleDelegate so the views can't be resized.